# Which actions must be physical when using celerity: all or just the additional ones?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

This question is about Vampire the Masquerade 3rd edition revised.

In the text for the Celerity discipline , the rule book says:

> **System**: The character spends a single blood point. The next turn, she
>   gains a number of additional full actions equal to her Celerity
>   rating. These additional actions must be physical (e.g., the vampire
>   cannot use a mental Discipline like Dominate multiple times in one
>   turn). So a vampire with Celerity 4 who spends a blood point may
>   perform a total of five physical actions in her next turn. The actions
>   occur at the end of the turn (the vampire's regular action still takes
>   place per her initiative roll).

My question is: must all actions be physical, or can the first one (i.e. the regular action) involve the use of another discipline, for instance? The rules are somehow confusing, because it first says that the "additional" actions must be physical, but then in the example it states that all actions are physical (i.e. a vampire with celerity 4 performs a total of 5 physical actions...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It clearly states that *additional* actions must be physical. So yes, the first action can be whatever you like. Example where all five actions are physical does not contradict it in any way, because the first action can be physical too, so I don't see what's confusing :)

I personally don't remember much about 3d ed, but that's also the way we play v20.

Basically as a Storyteller I'd err on the side of the player in a disagreement over mechanics, since mechanics are not that important in a story & roleplay focused game (which is what VtM is supposed to be) and ST still has many other tools to direct the story his way, so let the players have their toys. Especially if they spent XP on the disciplines expecting one thing, and turns out they are getting another. It's just more fair, more satisfying for players and has next to none negative effects from the ST's perspective anyway. Note that this approach does not work so well in a game where mechanics are more important, like DnD.

But in this particular case I don't even see what to disagree over. Rule is clear.

Comment: I totally agree with you and that is also my understanding. I just asked because the DM running our current game disagrees (most certainly because of what it is in the example) - hence I wanted an external opinion. Tks! :)

Comment: @LuizVieira just before posting I deleted a large part of my original answer, when I realized it's based on the assumption that you yourself are a Storyteller (Storyteller. Not DM), but there's nothing in your question indicating you are not just a player. It turns out you are a player :) In a case your ST reads this, I am adding it back.

Comment: Tks again @Sejanus (also for the ST instead of DM hint). Cheers.